# YouTube personal account as channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-monetization

I have a Gmail account. When I am already signed into Gmail account, YouTube shows me that I am signed in. So,

- Is this account considered as a channel by YouTube definitions?
- If yes, this channel will be eligible for monetization and YouTube play button rewards, once it reaches the threshold?
- Or Do I need to create a channel other than this to be eligible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- only if you created a channel - you can check this by clicking on your picture and selecting **My channel**. ...if you will be prompted to create a YouTube  channel you obviously don't have one

  [image: 0]
- monetization needs to be enabled first - you can see the status here: **https://www.youtube.com/account_monetization**

  [image]

Comment: i have not created any channel and when i click channels i see the account with my name

Comment: @melvin and yet you have one :)

Comment: Thank you. One more question. should i have the viewers and watch time requirement for monetization from now or from the time i started the channel ?

Comment: it should count since you enable it